# Form validity constantly returns true regardless of validator in the model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, paperclip

I'm using jQuery to hide and disable a submit button until a form has been validated with Paperclip's `validates_attachment_file_name`

It was immediately showing the button as soon as the form was clicked on and continued to show the button regardless of which file was selected.

I called `.checkValidity()` on the form and found out that it was constantly returning true. Once when the form was clicked on and again when a (any) file was selected.

Ruby model:

```
has_attached_file :file
validates_attachment_file_name :file, matches: [/string\Z/]
```

jQuery:

```
$('#form').bind('change click', function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
      $('#submit').show();
    } else {
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#submit').hide();
    }
  });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Where's your ajax?**

You're calling a `javascript` function to validate a `ruby` value.

As you should be aware, *javascript* is client-side, *ruby* is server-side. JS can only read what's literally printed in your ["DOM" (Document Object Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) ((HTML)).

Thus, your JS is completely false:

```
 $('#form').bind('change click', function() { // on FORM change (not file input)
    if ($(this).valid()) { // if FORM valid
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', false); // enable submit
      $('#submit').show(); // show submit
    } else {
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', true); //disable submit
      $('#submit').hide();  //hide submit
    }
  });
```

The above deals with the *form*. You need to deal with the submission of the form, and the response. A good example is here: http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com (click "login", submit and see returned data)

[image]

The way to fix your issue is to send the data to your server with "[ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))", taking the response and manipulating the DOM with it.

--

You'll be best doing this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "#form", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find("submit").attr('disabled', true);

   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          // do something when successful
      },
      error: function(data) {
          // this is where validation errors will show
      }
   });
});
```

You'll have to back this up with the appropriate controller action:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @object = Object.new object_params
      @object.save
      # conditional response here
   end
end
```

-

Now, you have an added problem of Javascript being unable to upload a file over XML. There's a technology which resolves this ([`jquery-file-upload`](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)), which we used [here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) (you'll have to sign up and go to the profile to upload a pic):

[image]

I can go into this with more detail if required.

Essentially, you just have to replace the above *ajax* functionality with [`.fileupload`](https://github.com/richpeck/video_demo/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.erb#L122):

```
$('#avatar').fileupload({

        url: '/profile/' + $(this).attr('data_id'),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
```

[Great example here](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example).